# How to modify internal symbols in mxnet?

Tags: python, mxnet

In mxnet 1.4 using the Python API, suppose I do

```
import mxnet as mx

a = mx.sym.var('a')
b = mx.sym.var('b')
c = mx.sym.var('c')

d = a + b  # Change that later
print(d)  # <Symbol _plus0>
e = d + c
```

Is there a way to modify an internal symbol of the graph after creating it? For example can we change `<Symbol _plus0>` to a subtraction instead of an addition? I would like to do something like `mx.sym.var('_plus0') = a - b`.

This would be useful when modifying a graph which has been loaded from a file.

I have checked this [tutorial](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/versions/master/tutorials/basic/symbol.html), the [docs](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/symbol/symbol.html), as well as the [source code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/master/python/mxnet/symbol/symbol.py) but couldn't find anything.